# .NET URI Routing MapPageRoute issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-routing

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

My Global.aspx:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute<TabsResource>("users");
}
```

> The non-generic method
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.MapPageRoute(string,
>   string, string, bool,
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,
>   System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary)'
>   cannot be used with type arguments

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it doesn't like the `<TabsResource>`. It doesn't appear to be a generic function. Also, I think you're missing a few arguments.

Comment: Mark is right, there is no generic version for MapPageRoute (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782977.aspx)!